# System Setting > Android SDK is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

may I know why my "Android SDK" menu is missing? How do I enable it back?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
 Go to Menu bar click ->View button and Select -> Toolbar
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R0d4.png]

Comment: No. It is not the answer.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for this option:


https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6aYF.png

Comment: What is the version of Android Studio you are using?

Comment: Android Studio version 2.2

Comment: Does it have "ContraintLayout for Android" option your SDK Manager? https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnE2i.png